# Размер массива в памяти

Tags: javascript

одинаковый ли объем памяти будут занимать массивы **a** и **b**?

```
a = [1,2];
```

и

```
b = [1];
b[1000] = 2;
```

Comment: никто не скажет наверняка, это может зависеть от чего угодно, от браузера, от движка js, и т.д. Например в хроме в инструментах разработчика были инструменты для проверки используемой памяти, но насколько они верны не могу сказать. Если рассуждать логически: в обоих объектах по два элемента, следовательно и размер занимаемой памяти должен совпадать

Comment: @Grundy как же, во втором случае, создается 1001 элемент

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев, не понял вопроса

Comment: @Grundy это не вопрос. `a.length = 2`, `b.length = 1001`. В b будут инициализированы индексы до используемого/мых

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев, вообще говоря - не будут

Comment: @Grundy будут, только будут undefined. инициализированы, я имею ввиду не объявлены, но место выделено

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев, есть какие-нибудь доказательства?

Comment: @Grundy консоль открой и попробуй) я же не просто так написал, что `a.length = 2`, `b.length = 1001`. Это фишка массивов

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев, а что пробовать-то? куда смотреть? где можно увидеть что _действительно создались_ индексы?

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев, консоль не дает понять. Проблема в том, что `a[10000000]` выдаст `undefined`, так же как и `a[2000]` выдаст `undefined` или как `a[200]` и `a[0.000023]`. Все эти индексы могут быть фантомными, если в них нет реальных данных. Консоль просто показывает эти значения, но не говорит, реально ли существует индекс или это всего лишь обертка которая возвращает результат `undefined` для любого несуществующего элемента на интервале.

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев, если был намек на то, что свойство `length` возвращает 1001, и отсюда следует, что в массиве 1001 элемент, то это неверно. свойство `length` как ни странно не показывает количество элементов в массиве.

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев, [_The value of the length property is numerically greater than the name of every own property whose name is an array index_](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-array-exotic-objects), то есть значение этого свойства, просто число, которое должно быть больше любого из числовых индексов. К тому же, если применить к разряженному массиву функцию `Object.keys` - то будут получены только реальные индексы, в случае `b` - это будут `[0, 1000]`

Answer (score 1):

Прочитайте [статью](http://learn.javascript.ru/array)

Массив может вести себя сходным образом с объектом:

```
var x = [];
x[1] = 1;
x['lala'] = 2;

console.log(x['lala'])
2
```

Из этого можно предположить, что под индекс заложен какой-то определенный тип данных, который позволяет хранить достаточно большое значение. Вы хотите сравнить 1 и 1000. Но даже на примере int32 эти оба числа всего лишь капля в море. Поэтому между 1 и 1000 индексом разницы нет.

Следующий пункт это: что с пропущенными индексами. Их нет, они ни чем не запонляются (опять же аналогия с объектом, когда вы обращаетесь к свойству которого в нем не существует, то получаете undefined).

Поэтому можно сделать вывод что разницы нет.

Однако с другой стороны использовать массив с дырами не целесообразно, т.к. он предназначен для хранения последовательности данных.

**Хотел написать это в комментарии, но по объему не прошло, т.к. до ответа не дотягивает**

Comment: в Вашем примере неявное преобразование массива в объект, посмотрите что Вам вернет x.length, а я говорил именно о массиве, но все равно спасибо за ответ

Comment: Да, в этом примере есть такое. length вернет как и полагается наибольшее целочисленное значение индекса. Имею в виду, что пропущенные индексы не инициализируются и ничем не заполняются, а тип данных индекса значительно превышает 1000. Таким образом ваши массивы А и Б должны быть равны в памяти. Кстати, с чем связан ваш вопрос ?

Comment: Хотел проверить свои знания, а сейчас решаю задачу оптимизации. Думаю как лучше реализовать "индекс" для больших структур чтоб избежать операций перебора.

Comment: Считаю, что вам стоит задать новый более специфичный вопрос по оптимизации, поскольку текущий не раскрывает суть вашей проблемы.